# Android Serial Port is being used for no permission to open

Tags: permissions, android, serial-port, serial-console

I have a Wandboard IMX 6 with Android OS. I can't read RS232 data. I was wrote an app for this on QtCreator with C++.

I have an issue. When i pressed the connect button i take `serial port is being used for no permission to open` error.

I listed my available serial ports a dropdown menu. I can see `ttymxc0` and `ttymxc2` on dropdown but can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the message should be "port is being used **or** no permission to open".

Your application probably needs to indicate in its manifest that it uses the serial port and/or request the necessary permission. [According to this,](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart) the needed permission would be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
```